# Is there anyway to set an NSString as a pointer to another string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, mobile, nsstring

For example, see the below code.

```
UITextField * myTextField = [[UITextField alloc]init];
NSString * myString = myTextField.text; //Set as reference to string here

NSLog(@"%@", myString); //Should be null

[myTextField setText:@"foobar"];

NSLog(@"%@", myString); //Should be foobar
```

I'm expecting that when the value of myTextField text to change, that "myString" changes as well.

I know the alternative way is to set a UITextField delegate and check "onChange" and change the string then, but I'm looking to see if there are potentially any other ways.

Comment: An NSString is an object, not a pointer.  An `NSString*` is a pointer, not an object.  They are two entirely different things.  And further note that an NSString is an *immutable* object -- once created it can't be changed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is doable in the way you want. the `text` property of `UITextField` is an `NSString` which is immutable. When it changes, a new `NSString` object is created. Aside from this, there is surely other stuff going on under the hood that makes this impossible.

The two easiest ways to do this would probably be

1. to set a `UITextFieldDelegate` as you said, and implement the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method.
2. Use `NSNotificationCenter` and observe the `UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification` event. Make sure to remove your object as an observer when it is dealloced

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` is an immutable class.  You can't change it.  All you can do is point your `NSString *` pointer variable at a different string.  You have to put another

```
myString = myTextField.text;
```

In there if you want this behaviour.